# Swiper slider still sliding when i'm cick over it and

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, swiper.js

I have that slider:

```
<div class="module mw2 mh2">
   <div class="swiper-2 swiper-module swiper-ap-1 swiper-home swiper-container-horizontal" style="cursor: -webkit-grab;">
       <div class="swiper-wrapper">
           <?php foreach ($slider_secondary as $image_info) { ?>
           <a class="swiper-slide bg op8 mp-gallery-1" data-background="<?php echo $image_info['image']; ?>" href="image/<?php echo $image_info['image_unresized']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image_info['titles'][$language_id]; ?>"></a>
           <?php } ?>
       </div>
       <!-- /swiper-wrapper -->

   <!-- Add Pagination -->
   <div class="swiper-ap-1-pag swiper-home-pagination swiper-pagination-fraction"></div>
   <!-- Add Arrows -->
   <div class="swiper-ap-1-nb swiper-home-button-next"></div>
   <div class="swiper-ap-1-pb swiper-home-button-prev"></div>
</div>
<!-- module 2 -->
</div>
```

and that js:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-2', {
    nextButton: '.swiper-2-nb',
    prevButton: '.swiper-2-pb',
    pagination: '.swiper-2-pag',
    paginationType: 'fraction',
    effect: 'slide',
    grabCursor: 'true',
    keyboardControl: false,
    loop: 'true'
});
```

So .. when i am click and manually change picture .. and stop for some seconds (but still clicked) slider still change pictures. On picture bellow i'm paused between these two images, but slider still sliding.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right solution, here:

```
$(".swiper-ap-1").hover(function(){
  this.swiper.stopAutoplay();
}, function(){
  this.swiper.startAutoplay();
});
```